# Trying to go from Edubuntu to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments

Recently upgraded to 12.04 however the problem started before that. I hoped that upgrading would solve the problem I created. Granted, I'm not sure how I created the problem.  :-)

Some time ago I downloaded Edubuntu from Ubuntu's Software Center. 
My plan was not to replace Ubuntu's desktop, however that is what happened.

All was good and then I upgraded (from a version before 11.10 if I remember correctly) and Edubuntu was here to stay. What bothers me is that Edubuntu doesn't seem to have all of the options that Ubuntu has/had.

After reading (either not enough or the wrong stuff), here is what I did to fix the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcQnu.png

After logging out I got the log in page (is that the right word?). It has Edubuntu (then the Edubuntu logo) 12.04 to the lower left. It gave me the following 4 options to log in (I tried all 4).

1. **Recovery Console** - This made me think that I really messed things up.
2. **Ubuntu**
3. **Ubuntu 2D** - Not sure how that differs from the above (number 2) Ubuntu.
4. **User Defined Session** - That also scared me. Somehow I remembered Ctrl-Alt-Delete or I'll still be stuck in there.

Now my desktop looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJbfg.png
This could mean that this is a Ubuntu desktop that only **shows** the Edubuntu icon.

However, I remember that I used to be able to do more in Ubuntu.
e.g., I was able to give folders little icons. I forgot what the icons were called.

I hope this is easy to understand. If not, please post what is not clear and I'll try to clarify if I can.

Also, when posting (and I hope you do), please assume that I don't know much about computers (as if this post doesn't point that out :-).

Answer (score 0):

You are in the unity desktop.Options are differents giving that it is based on Gnome 3 shell for the moment (on the other way, as you prefer). Now you've got other "features" like search you application (google like) etc.

You can give Gnome shell a try but if you want another desktop experience, you can switch to xubuntu-desktop which I think may suit best you needs to folder's icon changing.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I thought about Xubuntu. I assume this is done with **sudo apt-get xubuntu-desktop** or by using **Ubuntu's Software Center**.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear that you are experiencing issues with the removal of Edubuntu.
The problem here seems to be that you forgot to completely remove Edubuntu, so you basically installed Ubuntu on top of Edubuntu. To fix this, I would try removing Edubuntu completely. However, you might need to make a backup of the files you want to keep and make a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 as there might still be some bugs and problems during the conversion.

I wish you the best of luck in this and thank you for your patience and your valuable time.
Please feel free to post a reply if you ever have any more questions or for anything else in regards to this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your post. A fresh install is best (for many reasons), however I am resisting this. Why? I don't want to back up/archive my things. I **know** this is bad. I have **told** people that it is not a matter if your drive would fail, it is a matter of when. Back up today or feel pain tomorrow. Maybe I like pain (and I would feel a little pain if I lose certain things on my computer). Just seems that I am standing on the train tracks looking at the train coming. Will I get off before I get run over? It doesn't do much good to get off after you get hit. :-)

Comment: I'd save you!
We all know you got sudo privileges on that train anyway...